# WCF Service configuration

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest

I have a solution with a WCF service library (wcfservice) and a website (myweb).
wcfservice is a restful WCF service, it has 2 operations:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "User/{token}")]
UserInfo GetUserInfo(string token)

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "History/{user_id}")]
List<History> GetGameHistory(string user_id)
```

It also has a reference to other service (hosted on another machine), which gives actual userinfo for method 1.

This wcf service should be hosted in iis, through this website (only https allowed).
So I added reference to wcfservice in myweb, also added service.svc file that points to contract in wcfservice. At this point everything is ok. I can call `https://localhost/service.svc/History/xxx` from browser and it works.

What I want to do:
In myweb/default.aspx on Page_Load I want to call method GetUserInfo from wcfservice.
So I added service reference to wcfservice (am I doing wrong? I mean I already have a reference to dll files, but how do I call methods from them?) and since then can't get to make it work, I got all kind of errors (there is no endpoint listening... , The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure, etc...)

Can anyone help? :)
Some web.config examples would be great, or if I shouldn't be adding service reference in website, paste some code how to call service methods from dll.

**UPDATE:**
Uploaded VS2013 solution:

http://www.datafilehost.com/d/c3bdffe8

Please see readme.txt

Comment: Can you confirm the process flow:  website --> WCF SVC #1 --> WCF SVC #2 ... and where the issue exists (between WCF SVC #1 & #2) ... and provide the error information.

Comment: please see update section